# Error Setting up Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

Im Trying to setup google analytics in my app. I followed google tutorial below
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

But got following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to
```

when i put the code below into on create in the MainActivity:

```
 AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
     mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

**AnalyticsApplication Class:**

```
import android.app.Application;
```

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {

```
private Tracker mTracker;

synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
}
```

}

**GRADLE PROJECT**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

**GRADLE MODULE**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'


compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

**AndroidMaifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <service
        android:name=".CallDetectService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".RingerModeStateReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

I also have the configuration file copied into the app directory.
if i leave out the code in the Main Activity my app will run but nothing shows up
in my Analytics Account.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I Followed the google tutorial but nothing was happening then i when put the code into the Main Activity my app would crash.

Comment: Hi, can you show us your manifest file ?

Comment: No, need to use the big hammer of extending to application class for this. Get tracker by passing a context object to it.

Comment: Manifest does not have any application class declared in application tag.

Comment: Hi Thanks, could you give me a brief code example of how this would look thanks, as im still very amuater

Comment: @AndRSoid how do I correct this in the manifest?

Comment: Ive now managed to complete the google tutorial with no errors but nothing is showing up on my analytics account. does it take up to 48 hours to see changes? on youtube videos changes would appear nearly immediatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare application class in Manifest file use android:name="com.example.AnalyticsApplication" in Application tag.

Or use analytics helper class:

```
public class AnalyticsHelper {

    private static HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> sTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public static synchronized Tracker getTracker(Context context, TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!sTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
            Tracker t = null;

            switch (trackerId) {
                case APP_TRACKER:
                    t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.analytics_app_tracker);
                    break;
            }

            sTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
        }
        return sTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // App specific tracker ID
    }
}
```

and call `AnalyticsHelper.getTracker(this, TrackerName.APP_TRACKER)` your Application class.

Comment: After adding the Analytics Class to my androidManifest by directly adding ti to the manifest my app now runs, but still nothing shows up on my analytics account. do i have to send an event ? like a hit builder?

Comment: Yes it works! finally! Thank you @AndRSoid. adding the AnalyticsApplication class to my android manifest did the trick! it just took  a while for it to register. the real time is now working also and that works nearly instant, Thank you Happy Christmas! :)